# Разместить "значок" в правом верхнем углу текста

Tags: html, css

Неожиданно столкнулся с проблемой в такой задаче.
Есть блок фиксированной ширины. Внутри него может быть различного рода текст (динамический), как в одну, так и в две строки. Необходимо разместить "звездочку" в правом верхнем углу текста. Если текст в 2 строки, то в правом верхнем углу первой строки (непосредственно над окончанием слова). Пробовал и с помощью псевдоэлементов и с помощью дополнительного контейнера - не получается

```css
.item {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.txt{
  position: relative;
}
.required{
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right: -5px;
}

.pseudo{
  position: relative;
}
.pseudo:after{
  content: '*';
  color:blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <span class="txt">11111 <span class="required">*</span></span>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <span class="txt">2342342488 34288 <span class="required">*</span></span>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <span class="pseudo">11111</span>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <span class="pseudo">2342342488 34288</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, завернуть каждую строку в отдельный span возможности нет? Тогда бы всё через :after тривиально решалось

Comment: @andreymal, О таком не думал, т.к. изначально - это казалось тривиальной задачей)

Comment: @andreymal, кстати, завернуть каждую строку в тэг, тоже не простая задача. В строке ведь может быть несколько слов/предлогов. Плюс резиновость никто не отменял... Это я тут - пример упростил

Answer (score 1):

```css
.item {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.pseudo{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.pseudo:after{
  content: '*';
  color:blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <span class="pseudo">2342342488 34288</span>
</div>
```

Comment: не работает. В двустрочном тексте, звездочка находится в конце основного блока, а не над строкой

Comment: Ну так откорректируйте позицию звездочки, она стоит -5px, а `.pseudo` занимает ровно столько, сколько занимает текст, так как он `inline-block`

Comment: текст динамический

Comment: Вы можете скопировать код из вопроса и показать работающий пример (без харкода положения звездочки)

Comment: Скорректировал ответ

Comment: Ну так не находится же непосредственно над окончанием первой строки

Comment: Ну так подвиньте как надо, хоть абсолютно, хоть пэддингом. Принципиальное решение я показал. В моем коде звёздочка всегда будет стоять в верхнем правом углу при любом объеме текста.